# applescript: How to click color labels in finder

Tags: cocoa, automation, applescript, desktop

I'm trying to to click one of the labels ("Red", "Green", "Yellow", etc) on the sidebar of a finder window?

So far I tried

`tell application "Finder"
  click label "Blue"
end tell`

but this doesn't work.

Comment: The Finder dictionary doesn't support that. Maybe it's possible with GUI scripting. Actually clicking on a tag shows a Spotlight search/filter result.

Comment: That's not how application scripting works. If you want to do that, you need to learn AppleScript basics first. However, you'll need to search for information on setting Finder tags via the command line `xattr` tool as Finder's scripting interface is ancient and hasn't been updated to support this.